# Is my monitor too close to the window?

Tags: display, window

I just got a new monitor for my pc delivered today. I saw in the manual that I should not put it too close to a window as it needs to be kept away from sunlight and moisture.

This is a problem as I've long had my pc and monitor in the corner next to the window. I could move the table away from it and put it where my bookshelf is now. But where my pc is now it has easy access to the only phone line in the room and it would be a hassle to unload and move the bookshelf. Also I would have to put the bookshelf in the corner where the monitor was and sunlight isn't good for books either.

I've included a picture of my current monitor on the table I have set up. I want to ask, is that too close to the window?

Also the window faces north-east, so any sunlight coming through would be angled away from the monitor.

[click to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbQjN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem. I keep my monitor at the same place. This part of the manual is mostly to avoid responsibility by the manufacturer in the 1% cases where something can happen.

Comment: Maybe more like 0.01% . You don't want condensation from a frigid uninsulated windowpane dripping on the monitor, is all.